# Listing all blobs in a container in Azure Functions Isolated Process

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I've looked everywhere to figure out how to list all of the blobs in an Azure Storage  container using an Isolated-Process Function App.  This used to be dead simple using an In-Process Function App, but I'm stuck finding an answer that works with Isolated-Process.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the blobs in an Azure Storage container using an Azure Functions Isolated Process, you can use the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` NuGet package.

**Blobs in Container:**

[image]

I used the below code and it worked for me.

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("Connection String");
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("Container");

            List<string> blobNames = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("...List of Blobs...");
            await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                blobNames.Add(blobItem.Name);
               
                Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Name);
            }

            return new OkObjectResult(blobNames);
        }

    }
```

Output from the browser using functions.

[image]

Output from console using functions.

[image]

Output from the Azure after publishing the function app to Azure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply.  Basically, what you're saying is I need to roll my own, using an explicit BlobContainerClient.  I'd hoped that there'd be something built in that would have leveraged the existing connection, but c'est la vie!